# Why is there no Linq method to return distinct values by a predicate?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I want to get the distinct values in a list, but not by the standard equality comparison.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
return myList.Distinct( (x, y) => x.Url == y.Url );
```

I can't, there's no extension method in Linq that will do this - just one that takes an `IEqualityComparer`.

I can hack around it with this:

```
return myList.GroupBy( x => x.Url ).Select( g => g.First() );
```

But that seems messy. It also doesn't quite do the same thing - I can only use it here because I have a single key.

I could also add my own:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>( 
    this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T,T,bool> compare )
{
    //write my own here
}
```

But that does seem rather like writing something that should be there in the first place.

Anyone know why this method isn't there?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's annoying, certainly. It's also part of my "MoreLINQ" project which I must pay some attention to at some point :) There are plenty of other operations which make sense when acting on a projection, but returning the original - MaxBy and MinBy spring to mind.

As you say, it's easy to write - although I prefer the name "DistinctBy" to match OrderBy etc. Here's my implementation if you're interested:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return source.DistinctBy(keySelector,
                                 EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
         IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
        }
        if (comparer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
        }
        return DistinctByImpl(source, keySelector, comparer);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>
        (IEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
         IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer - I might use that! Any idea why they skipped all these ...By(Predicate) methods?

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. I'll blog about the MoreLinq project when I've got a significant set of features... basically it'll be an open source project with extensions to LINQ to Objects, and probably Push LINQ too.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess for parity with the IQueryable<T> options, and what is realistic (without getting sick) in TSQL. So DISTINCT(table.column) is fine, but you'd need a handy key and some more complex TSQL for DistinctBy...

Comment: That's a good point Marc - if you'd posted it as an answer I'd have voted it up.

Answer (score 36):

> But that seems messy.

It's not messy, it's correct.

- If you want `Distinct` Programmers by FirstName and there are four Amy's, which one do you want?
- If you `Group` programmers By FirstName and take the `First` one, then it is clear what you want to do in the case of four Amy's.

> I can only use it here because I have a single key.

You can do a multiple key "distinct" with the same pattern:

```
return myList
  .GroupBy( x => new { x.Url, x.Age } )
  .Select( g => g.First() );
```

Answer (score 3):

Jon, your solution is pretty good. One minor change though. I don't think we need EqualityComparer.Default in there. Here is my solution (ofcourse the starting point was Jon Skeet's solution)

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        //TODO All arg checks
        HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            TKey key = keySelector(item);
            if (!keys.Contains(key))
            {
                keys.Add(key);
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be better than Jon's solution. `new HashSet<TKey>()` will use `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` anyway and by doing it your way you lose the ability to override it (for instance if `TKey` is `string` and you want case insensitivity). Also Jon uses the `HashSet.Add` method, while you use `HashSet.Contains` and then `HashSet.Add` - two operations. Admittedly you'd need a massive set to notice the difference, but why make it slower?

Answer (score 2):

Using AmyB's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520315/1835379), I've written a small `DistinctBy` extension method, to allow a predicate to be passed:

```
/// <summary>
/// Distinct method that accepts a perdicate
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the t source.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the t key.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The source.</param>
/// <param name="predicate">The predicate.</param>
/// <returns>IEnumerable&lt;TSource&gt;.</returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">source</exception>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return source
        .GroupBy(predicate)
        .Select(x => x.First());
}
```

You can now pass a predicate to group the list by:

```
var distinct = myList.DistinctBy(x => x.Id);
```

Or group by multiple properties:

```
var distinct = myList.DistinctBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Title });
```