# LINQ to DataSet, distinct by multiple columns

Tags: linq, distinct, linq-to-dataset

Just wanted to check if there is way to do distinct by multiple columns. Thanks in advance!!!

BTW, I found a great LINQ extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520030/why-is-there-no-linq-method-to-return-distinct-values-by-a-predicate/520046#520046) but need some guidance to use it for multiple columns

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, you can do the projection first:

```
var qry = db.Customers.Select(cust => new {cust.ID, cust.Name, cust.Region})
                    .Distinct();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var qry = (from cust in db.Customers
          select new {cust.ID, cust.Name, cust.Region}).Distinct();
```

That do?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of Distinct you can use Groupby and then selecting the Top Most record of each group

[How to LINQ Distinct by Multiple Fields without anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148809/how-to-linq-distinct-by-multiple-fields-without-anonymous-types)

> > return from o in objEntity
> >
> > ```
> >               group o by new
> >               {
> >                   o.Field1,
> >                   o.Field2,
> >                   o.Field3,
> >                   o.Field4,
> >                   o.Field5
> >               } into grp
> >               select grp.FirstOrDefault();
> > ```

This will give you the **EntityObject** Rather than the **AnonymousType**

Answer (score 5):

By "distinct by multiple columns" what you really mean is a group by.

When you ask for distinct, it means that you are getting ALL the distinct rows, or, a group by using all the columns in the table.

If you want to only get distinct groupings for a subset of the columns, then use a group by in your clause, specifying the columns to group by.  Then, select the groups, as you only want one set of keys for each group.

Answer (score 3):

Another easy option is to create a single distinct string.

```
var result = collection.DistinctBy(c => c.Field1 + "." + c.Field2 + "." + c.Field3);
```

Answer (score 1):

var qry = (from cust in db.Customers
          select new {cust.ID, cust.Name, cust.Region}).GroupBy(x => new { x.Name,x.Region}).select(z => z.OrderBy(i => i.cust).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();