# How to LINQ Distinct by Multiple Fields without anonymous types

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a table named **CLASS** with the Fields

```
    **{BATCH, DEGREE, DEPT, SEM, SECTION, GROUP }**
```

I has the Following Records

> > Record1: **{ 2009 , B.E , CSE , 3Sem , ASec , 1Group }**
> >
> > Record2: **{ 2009 , B.E , CSE , 3Sem , ASec , 2Group }**
> >
> > Record3: **{ 2009 , B.E , ECE , 4Sem , ASec , 1Group }**
> >
> > Record4: **{ 2009 , B.E , ECE , 4Sem , ASec , 2Group }**

I Need to Select Distinct Records Ignoring the **GROUP** and considering only the following

> > **{BATCH, DEGREE, DEPT, SEM, SECTION }**

So it should return me the following **2 Distinct Records**

> > ```
> >                   Record1: **{ 2009 , B.E , CSE , 3Sem , ASec , 1Group }**
> > ```
> >
> > **DistinctRecord: 1------------------------**(OR)**
> >
> > ```
> >                   Record2: **{ 2009 , B.E , CSE , 3Sem , ASec , 2Group }**
> > ```
> >
> > -----**(AND)**
> >
> > ```
> >                   Record3: **{ 2009 , B.E , ECE , 4Sem , ASec , 1Group }**
> > ```
> >
> > **DistinctRecord: 2**------------------------**(OR)**
> >
> > ```
> >                   Record4: **{ 2009 , B.E , ECE , 4Sem , ASec , 2Group }**
> > ```

Now i'm using the following LINQ Query

```
    public static object GetDistictClasses(IQueryable<Class> AllClasses)
    {
        return (from c in AllClasses
                group c by new { c.Batch, c.Degree_ID, c.Specialization_ID, c.CurrentSemester, c.Section_ID } into grp
                select new 
                {
                    grp.Key.Batch,
                    grp.Key.Degree_ID,
                    grp.Key.Specialization_ID,
                    grp.Key.CurrentSemester,
                    grp.Key.Section_ID
                }).Distinct();
    }
```

But it returns me a **Ananymous Type**, but i need the Actual **Class Type**

Could some one Help Me...
thank You..

Regrads
Pradeep

Comment: That should return an `IQueryable<DistinctClass>` (assuming the way you initialized that is legal for the type).  The only anonymous objects here are your keys.  p.s., the final call to `Distinct()` is not necessary since the grouping should have taken care of that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
return
    from c in AllClasses
    group c by new
    {
        c.Batch, 
        c.Degree_ID, 
        c.Specialization_ID, 
        c.CurrentSemester, 
        c.Section_ID 
    } into grp
    select grp.First();
```

This takes every first `Class` from the given group, thus returns a Entity object instead of a anonymous type.

Comment: Legend. This has completely saved me! Thanks so much.

Comment: clarifying question: why, when I use `...group c by new [type] {...} into grp ...` does this not work?  I still get all the records instead of just the distinct ones.  Is this a problem with the class's GetHashCode method or something?

Answer (score 21):

Lets make it simple - distinct is done on two properties:

- the Id of the user and
- the group id

also this will return the same object type.

```
var distinctgroupSubscriptions = groupSubscriptions.GroupBy(item => new { item.User.Id, item.Group.GroupId }).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: its pretty old post, but this is amazing linq

Comment: its pretty old response, but this comment is amazing

Comment: Simple & easy approach, better than using extension methods provided by MoreLINQ.