# How do I get distinct rows along with the count of identical rows in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

In SQL this would be easy for me...

```
SELECT browser, browser_version, page_name, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM traffic
GROUP BY browser, browser_version, page_name
```

This would return one row for each unique combination of browser, browser_version, page_name, along with the count of duplicates.

I'd like to do the same thing in Linq, but I'm not sure how to do it.

By the way, I'm not using SQL in this case because the data didn't come from SQL.  It came from Windows Azure Table Storage.  And I'm working with the data in-memory.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706866/linq-to-dataset-distinct-by-multiple-columns

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869001/linq-group-by-multiple-fields-syntax-help

Comment: @M.Babcock - That topic only shows how to get distinct rows... it doesn't get a count.

Comment: Are you using DataTables to store it in memory?

Comment: @Tim - Currently I'm working with the data in IEnumerable form because that's how it comes out of my DataSource classes by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query =
    from t in traffic
    group t by new { t.browser, t.browser_version, t.page_name } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.browser,
        g.Key.browser_version,
        g.Key.page_name,
        Count = g.Count()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man.  My problem was a little more complex than the example I gave.  I also had to get the latest date for every grouping.  But your solution was perfect and helped me figure it all out.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a similar method:

```
var results = traffic.GroupBy(t => new { t.browser, t.browser_version, t.page_name });

foreach(var group in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2} has {3} items.", 
            group.Key.browser, 
            group.Key.browser_version, 
            group.Key.page_name, 
            group.Count());
}
```