# SQL to Linq - selecting first matching rows

Tags: .net, sql, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Ive been struggling to find an answer to this task problem I am solving, despite spending the morning no here searching.
I have looked into the MIN/MAX clauses but cannot seem to fit it in my scenario properly.

I am performing this simple LINQ query where i search all rows where the column matches

```
using (DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext())
        {
            var routes = (

                          from txcalllines in db.TxcAllLines
                          where
                              txcalllines.LineName == searchString
                          select txcalllines);

            return routes.ToList();
        }
```

And this returns these results:

```
FILE                           LINE   START               FINISH
output_txc_45486m.xml           486   North Station       Friswell Place
SVRAYAO486-20121008-22264.xml   486   Dunoon              Inveraray
SVRAYAO486-20121008-22265.xml   486   Dunoon              Inveraray
SVRAYAO486-20121008-22266.xml   486   Dunoon              Inveraray
SVRGMB04860-20120103-5774.xml   486   BURY                RADCLIFFE
SVRGMB04860-20120103-5775.xml   486   BURY                RADCLIFFE
SVRYNAO486-20120217-44588.xml   486   Selby Bus Stn       Pollington Circular
```

The problem is, running this query returns several rows of the same route (you can see LINE, START, and FINISH are the same), where I only want to return the first matching row of each route.

So the desired result would be:

```
FILE                           LINE   START               FINISH
output_txc_45486m.xml           486   North Station       Friswell Place
SVRAYAO486-20121008-22264.xml   486   Dunoon              Inveraray
SVRGMB04860-20120103-5774.xml   486   BURY                RADCLIFFE
SVRYNAO486-20120217-44588.xml   486   Selby Bus Stn       Pollington Circular
```

Comment: Good point, I was not meant to call .ToList() twice.

Comment: It just puts it in a list some my client application can read it nicely. (The above code is from a WCF service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` then get the first element of each group.

```
var routes = (from txcalllines in db.TxcAllLines
              where txcalllines.LineName == searchString
              group txcalllines by new { txcalllines.Start, txcalllines.Finish } into g  // Groups the txcalllines by the pair (Start, Finish)
              select g.First());  // Gets the first intem of the group
```

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks for your answer, but it does not compile. It complains of several issues, including "invalid expression term 'in'", and expecting a few ) and ;

Comment: @DanSewell I have update my post (just changed _in_ into _into).

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question, I apologize... Maybe this could be to help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/706903/1380061

Comment: Sorry I am not sure you understand, I want to return several rows (edited question to make this clearer)