# Remove the duplcated element and then sort them with Linq

Tags: xml, linq

I have an XML file :

```
  <School>
    <SchoolID>9</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>3</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>3</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>3</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>4</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>1</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>3</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>9</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>2</SchoolID>
  </School>
```

The expecting results should be like:

```
 <School>
    <SchoolID>1</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>2</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>3</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>4</SchoolID>
    <SchoolID>9</SchoolID>
 </School>
```

My C# code:

```
var xdoc = XElement.Load(filePath + "input.xml");
var temp = xdoc.Descendants("SchoolID").OrderBy(x => x.Value).Distinct();
xdoc.Save(filePath + "output_final.xml");
```

However, the result does not change anything.

My temp value is what I want, how can I update my output xml result?

Many thanks.

DY

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions by clicking the hollow check next to your favorite answer for each question.  Doing so will give you more reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Your LINQ statement only creates a statement that can be executed later, it doesn't modify anything. The following solves it quickly:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath + "input.xml");
xdoc.Root.ReplaceAll(xdoc
    .Descendants("SchoolID")
    .DistinctBy(e => e.Value)
    .OrderBy(e => e.Value));
xdoc.Save(filePath + "output_final.xml");
```

Comment: Hi Yuriy, thanks very much. 

Is there any easy way I could get the xml file updated?

Comment: There is no `DistinctBy` method.

Comment: Sorry the DistinctBy came from http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var ids = xdoc.Descendants("SchoolID")
              .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value))
              .Distinct()
              .OrderBy(x => x);

var newDoc = new XElement("School", ids.Select(i => new XElement("SchoolID", i));
newDoc.Save(filePath + "output_final.xml");
```

You ned to call `int.Parse` to make sure it sorts correctly if an ID is more than 10, and you need to call `Select` before `Distinct` because `XElement` is compared by reference, meaning that no two `XElement`s are equal, even if they have the same content.  You could write your own `IEqualityComparer`, but this way is much easier.

Comment: Maybe reverse the Distinct and OrderBy?

Comment: There is no `DistinctBy` method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520030/why-is-there-no-linq-method-to-return-distinct-values-by-a-predicate

Comment: Had a feeling it came from MoreLinq/I created it. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

I got another way to solve this problem by using XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="SchoolID">
<xsl:if test="not(node()) or not(preceding-sibling::node()[.=string(current())])">
<SchoolID>
   <xsl:value-of select="SchoolID"/>
</SchoolID>
</xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>
```

This code dose not include sorting.

Thanks.

DY