# Linq Distinct based on property of object

Tags: linq, distinct

Is it possible to get the distinct elements of a `List` based on a property of the objects in the `List`?

Someting like: `Distinct(x => x.id)`

What's not usefull for me is following: `.Select(x => x.id).Distinct()` because then I would get back a `List<int>` instead of `List<MyClass>`

Comment: Nearly same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520030/why-is-there-no-linq-method-to-return-distinct-values-by-a-predicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need DistinctBy. It's not part of the standard .NET libraries, but Jon Skeet made an implementation of it for Linq to objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520030/why-is-there-no-linq-method-to-return-distinct-values-by-a-predicate). It's also included in [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like a grouping construct to me, because you need to decide which of the supposedly identical object you actually want to return

```
var q = from x in foo
        group x by x.Id into g
        select g.First(); // or some other selection from g
```

Just because Id is identical across multiple items doesn't mean that the items are identical on other properties, so you need to explicitly decide which item is returned.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` and pass that to `Distinct`:

```
class SomeType {
    public int id { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeType> {
    public bool Equals(SomeType x, SomeType y) {
        return x.id == y.id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeType obj) {
        return obj.id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
// elements is IEnumerable<SomeType>
var distinct = elements.Distinct(new EqualityComparer());
// distinct is IEnumerable<SomeType> and contains distinct items from elements
// as per EqualityComparer
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload on `Enumerable.Distinct()` that takes `IEqualityComparer`.

Here's an example where I used it to filter integers by parity:

```
    class IntParitiyComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
    {
        public bool Equals(int x, int y)
        {
            return x % 2 == y % 2;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int obj)
        {
            return obj % 2;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Distinct(new IntParitiyComparer());

        foreach (var y in x) Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
```

It's clumsy; `DistinctBy` would be cleaner.